# PHP - If array key exist and not empty

Tags: php, arrays

I got the following array

```
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => John Doe
    [2] => john
    [3] => john@doe.com
    [4] => lorem
    [5] => Lorem, Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
)
```

Basically I am reading those values from CSV file, I want to validate the data before inserting into the database, here is the basic validation i want to apply

- Check if array contains 6 elements
- All fields are required and not empty

Here is what i am doing:

```
if (count($value) == 6) {
    $params = array(
        'id' => array_key_exists(0, $value) && !empty($value[0]) ? $value[0]: null,
        'name' => array_key_exists(1, $value) && !empty($value[1]) ? $value[1]: null,
        'username' => array_key_exists(2, $value) && !empty($value[2]) ? $value[2]: null,
        'email' => array_key_exists(3, $value) && !empty($value[3]) ? $value[3]: null,
        'password' => array_key_exists(4, $value) && !empty($value[4]) ? $value[4]: null,
        'position' => array_key_exists(5, $value) && !empty($value[5]) ? $value[5]: null
    );
}
```

I am wondering, what would be the better way of handling this? what i don't like is the repetition, Probably i can solve by putting it inside a loop, I want to know from you how would you do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just simply use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to check if the value isn't empty and [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) it with the keys, like this:

```
if(count($value) == 6) {
    $params = array_combine(["id", "name", "username", "email", "password", "position"], array_map(function($v) {
        return ( !empty($v) ? $v : NULL );
    }, $value));
}
```

Comment: This looks great, the syntax that you are using seems that of PHP 5.4, and i want to make sure it is compatible with 5.3 because of server limitation, I assume i just have to update the first parameter of array_combine, and i am good to go?

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar Yes, just change the `[]` array syntax to the old `array()` syntax and you're good to go and the snippet should work fine for php 5.3

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar You're welcome! Enjoy your day :D

Answer (score 0):

one way is to use `array_merge()`, you can make a function like this:

```
public function merge_my_array($params = []){

  return array_merge(
    [
      'id' => null,
      'name' => null,
      'username' => null,
      'email' => null,
      'password' => null,
      'position' => null
    ], $params);
}
```

now if you call the function like this:

```
$array = merge_my_array(['id'=>1, 'name'=>'John', 'email'=>'john@gmail.com']);
```

variable $array will have:

id 1, name John, email john@gmail.com and all the other attributes null.

And if you call the function without passing parameters it is ok, its not mandatory and will return an array with all those 6 attributes all null. Like this:

```
$array = merge_my_array();
```